# Getting 'The link you followed has expired.' when trying to upload plugin in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to upload a plugin but getting this `The link you followed has expired`. After looking for solutions I added these 3 lines of code at the end of my theme's 'functions.php' file:

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '256M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '256M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

but that didn't fix it as I can still see `Maximum Upload File Size: 2mb` in `Media > Add New` page.

After trying that, I added `max_execution_time = 60` and `max_input_vars = 3000` in `php.ini` file located in `/etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini` but it does not take effect as my Wordpress website's Site Health still shows the default values.

Also tried after adding these in `wp-config.php`

```
@ini_set( 'max_input_vars' , 3000 );
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '256M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '256M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

but doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

About my server, it's a VPS and I'm using Nginx as reverse proxy. I had issues while uploading a theme but I added `client_max_body_size 20M;` in `nginx.conf` file. Then added these:

```
set_time_limit(300);
@ini_set( 'max_input_vars' , 3000 );
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
define('FS_METHOD','direct');
```

in `wp-config.php` file.

The reason I'm telling what I did is to know if I have done something wrong and the current config in the server side.

Please tell me how to fix the plugin issue. This is the first time I'm trying to deploy WP website in a VPS.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is most probably not related to the hosting environment, and If I were you, I would check the "error_log" file inside the /wp-admin/ directory to troubleshoot this further. However, if you do not manage to find anything useful there, I would definitely recommend reaching out to the tech support of your host to check this further, as they will be able to troubleshoot this much easier than anyone here lacking access to the environment. If they lack support, you might want to consider switching to a new one that could help in similar situations.